# Joining tables from separate postgres tables with Ecto.Query

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I have a postgres database with two schemas that I often need to join between.  I’ve been using the `Repo.all(%{query | prefix: "customers"})` when it’s just one table, but I'm not sure the proper way to add a prefix when I'm joining `"customers.contacts"` with `"accounts.details"` in one query.

Comment: Do you NEED to prefix? Ecto will figure out what table the column is from if you build the query correctly so there shouldn't be a need to prefix everything explicitly?

Comment: Without the prefix, ecto seems to default to the public schema where it can't find either table, throwing a table does not exist error.

Comment: In your model, try adding `@schema_prefix "my_prefix"` which will automatically prefix the queries with the schema it belongs to assuming you're using ecto 2+ https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/lib/ecto/schema.ex#L38